# I'm new to react, tried creating first app, 'Square' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef throws this error

Tags: reactjs

When i try to create first react application which is provided in the docs, i'm getting this error hence app is not compiling. the error is  **'Square' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef**.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
serviceWorker.unregister();

    class Board extends React.Component {

    renderSquare(i) {
        return <Square value={i} />;
      }

}
```

Comment: did you forgot to `import Square` somewhere?

Comment: Yes. i forgot to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is here:
If you are going to use the Square component, you need to create a class and then import it in main.js.

So you might have something like this:

```
// src/square.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Square extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Square</div>;
  }
}
```

Then in your main.js you use it like this:

```
// src/main.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import Square from './square';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
serviceWorker.unregister();

class Board extends React.Component {

    renderSquare() {
      return <Square />;
    }
    render() {
      return this.renderSquare();
    }

}
```